# How To Get the Aggregated Usage of CPU in GRAFANA when hyperthreading is enabled

Tags: performance-testing, prometheus, monitoring, grafana, promql

We are running GRAFANA/PROMETHEUS to monitor our CPU metrics and find aggregated CPU Usage of all cpus. the problem is we have enabled hyperthreading and when we stress CPU the percentage exceeds from 100%. my question is how to limit that cpu usage to show only usage in 100% not more even if cpu is highly utilized.

P.S i have tried setting the max and min limit in grafana but still the graph spikes goes above that limit.

Kindly give me the right query for this problem.

The queries I have tried are given below.

```
sum(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="localhost",job="node", mode!="idle"}[5m]))*100


100 - avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="localhost",job="node", mode!="idle"}[5m]))*100
```

and other similar queries we have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the most helpful query.

```
(1 - avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="$instance",job="$job",mode!="idle"}[5m])))*100
```

Replace your instance IP and your node exporter job name.

Answer (score 1):

To get single CPU core usage:

`sum by(cpu) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="<JOB_NAME>", mode!="idle"}[$__rate_interval]))`

[CPU usage per core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYsL.png)

Then avg to get the whole CPU usage:

`avg (sum by(cpu) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="<JOB_NAME>", mode!="idle"}[$__rate_interval])))`

[CPU usage all core](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD7sM.png)

You can see the usage not overflow 100% when machine do compile job.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to "cap" a variable or expression result to a maximum value (that is, 100) you could simply use the Prometheus function [clamp_max](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#clamp_max).

Thus, you could do:

```
clamp_max(<expr>, 100)
```

Comment: I have no idea how can i use clamp to show all cpu usage i have with hyperthreading enabled?